# How to compute size of MessagePack .NET object?

Tags: c#, msgpack

If I have a class without any variable sized objects (e.g. strings, lists, etc.), is there some utility function in the [MessagePack](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#object-type-serialization) library to compute the size of the binary representation of the object?

Example class:

```
[MessagePackObject]
class Foo {
  [Key(0)]
  public int A { get; set; }
  [Key(1)]
  public float B { get; set; }
}
```

My current best bet is to simply serialize an object and measure it's length.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the final object to a helper method to get the bytes used, i.e.;

```cs
var obj = new Foo { A = 1, B = 2};
var bytes = Foo.ToMessagePack();
Debug.WriteLine($"size in bytes is {bytes.Length}");
```

And the extension method;

```cs
public static class Helpers
{
    public static byte[] ToMessagePack<T>(this T data) => MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is my current best bet as well :)